# NGINX Format for AWS EB Web Sockets

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, parse-server

Does anyone have a formatted nginx.config file for upgrading AWS EB to allow for web sockets? It would be great to see your example nginx.config files for this. I found I need to setup the nginx.config from this [link](http://sunnycyk.com/2017/03/parse-server-websocket-and-aws-lb/).

Here's the one I thought was going to work before I tried other things but it and various similar versions I put through a YAML validator gave deployment errors:

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    content: |
        http {
    client_max_body_size 50M;
        }

    client_max_body_size 50M;
    upstream nodejs {
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        keepalive 256;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
            set $year $1;
            set $month $2;
            set $day $3;
            set $hour $4;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_set_header        Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        Connection      "upgrade";
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location /static {
            alias /var/app/current/static;
        }

    }

container_commands:
removeconfig:
    command: "rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf"
```

I've tried about a dozen formats I've found across the internet to no avail including from the following links:

[Web Socket Issue for Node.js app on AWS EB for Parse Live Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46121793/web-socket-issue-for-node-js-app-on-aws-eb-for-parse-live-query)

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/3611

Comment: What is the issue you face with the current config you use?

Comment: Can you share access and error logs please